# Nav bar is not showing up on second page of website

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, nav

I've gotten this navigation bar to work on my landing page, and I want it to look the same on the second page as well, but it's not showing up. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I just copied/pasted from the first page.

This is probably just missing something small, but I've been staring at it for a while and can't seem to figure it out.

This is the code to my second page that it won't show up on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Reservations</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reservations.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="icon" href="travel.png">
</head>
<body>
<style>
  h1 {
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
  }
 .form-group {
   width: 400px;
   text-align: justify;
 }
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

</style>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="travelindex.html">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  <h1><strong>Reservation Information</strong></h1>
    <form action="contactform.php" method="post" id="reservationform">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="adults">Adults</label>
      <input type="number" name="adultsNo" id="adultsNo" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="children">Children</label>
      <input type="number" name="children" id="children" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <select name="city" id="city"  style="width: 250px" class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled>Select</option>
      <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
      <option value="Vancouver">Vancouver</option>
      <option value="New_York_City">New York City</option>
      <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
      <option value="Cancun">Cancun</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="activity">Activity</label>
      <select name="activity" id="activity" style="width: 250px" class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="traveldate">Travel Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="traveldate" id="traveldate" style="width: 250px" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" form="reservationform" value="Submit" style="width: 100px">Submit</button><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="reset" value="Reset" style="width: 100px" >Reset</button>

  </form>

  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="megatravel.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Could be that you are using an outdated version/link with an error

Comment: That's changing the Bootstrap version though

Comment: @brooksrelyt I knew it was something simple! haha. Thank you!